# Unreadable codes while using read() in python

Tags: python, powershell

I'm learning python2.7 in Windows 8.1.

I used echo "XXX" to create a new file, and then I used python to read it, but it output unreadable files.
But when I used GUI to type something into a new file then read it in python it works.
Is there anyone could help me please ?

I wrote this in powershell 2.0

`PS C:\Users\Fingal> echo "Stack Overflow is such a good site." > test.txt`

And then I wrote this in Notepad++, and save it as test.txt in C:\Users\Fingal

```
from sys import argv
script, file_name = argv
txt = open(file_name)
print txt.read()
txt.close()
```

Then I back to powershell and type:

```
PS C:\Users\Fingal\> python test.py test.txt
a ataaacaka a0avaearafalaoawa aiasa asauacaha aaa agaoaoada asaiattaea.aa
```

It output unreadable code.

Fingal

Comment: Can you post the code that you are using to read the file?

Comment: How much do you understand about codecs? Your GUI created data in one codec, `echo` in another. You may want to read [this article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) and [this article too](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) before continuing.

Comment: Without code and file samples we cannot do anything to help you further however.